# How to connect to Java Applet using Python

Tags: java, python

I am looking for a solution.

I am trying to automate user interaction on a web application which is having embedded java applet in it. Based on what I've found on the internet I know there are specific testing frameworks like FEST-swing for Java or Abbot for C# which can be good to solve this problem. My question is: are there similar testing frameworks but which would be native for python? Or maybe it is possible to use FEST-swing with Jython?

I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your test-cases in Python you could have a look at http://marathontesting.com/ as I found in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154726/1088584).

As I understand the MarathonITE supports Applet testing: http://marathontesting.com/tutorials/page/2/#!prettyPhoto[]/1/